# maven: generate library jar with classes inside a package

Tags: maven

I've created a project (springboot service).

I need to generate:

- the main executable jar, already managed by `spring-boot-maven-plugin`
- also, I need to generate a non-executable jar from some included classes (everything inside `me.jeusdi.serializers` package.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Create a multi-module project which has two modules:

- the executable JAR
- The non-executable JAR